# Change color of Wordpress page breaks

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress page (Sofa QandA). I want to change the color of the grey page breaks on the home screen. I couldn't find the the relevant code in css.

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the horizontal break is a `<hr>` element you can style it as you want.

```
hr {
   /* your styles here */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zSWbg/5/)

In the case that it is not an `hr` element, you could right click on it and select 'Inspect Element' to see how the line break is being formed, and what styles are being applied to it.